# Error on Safe Deploy: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChainId')

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to implement Gnosis into a react Webapp with using metamask as provider. Upon following the Setup Tutorial i stumbled on this error:

> Safe.ts:164 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChainId')

My component is as follows:

```
  import Safe, { SafeFactory, SafeAccountConfig } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'

  const web3Provider = window.ethereum;
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3Provider)
  const safeOwner = provider.getSigner(0)

  const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers,
  signer: safeOwner
  })

  const createSafe = async () =>{
    const safeFactory =  await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter });
    const safeSdk =  await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig });  
    safeSdk();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep having this same issue - any idea how to sort this out? Or why is it  the reason for keep happening?
I am following the tutorial [DeploySafe](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#deploysafe) and sorted already the problems with CommonJS and ES6 but this is happening in both...

Answer (score 1):

if anyone face this same error, there is a line missing in the example here https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-web3-lib#initialization  `const web3 = new Web3(provider);`
after `const web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')`